# DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body when trying to send embeds

Tags: node.js, discord.js

This is one of the first commands I wrote whilst I've been learning, and recently it stopped working. I fiddled with it a little, but can't see where the problem comes from. When I run `~userinfo` the following error comes up in the console:

```
Unhandled Rejection at: DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body
embed.footer.icon_url: Not a well formed URL.
```

This is the code for userinfo:

```
    if (command === 'userinfo') {
        var embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setTitle('User Info')
        .addField('Username', message.author.tag)
        .addField('Server', message.guild.name)
        .setColor(0xFF8AFF)
        .setThumbnail(message.author.avatarURL)
        .setFooter('Akasuki', version, client.user.avatarURL);
        message.channel.send(embed);
    }
```

Changing `message.channel.send()` to `message.channel.sendEmbed()` brings up errors, and there's been nothing wrong with using `send()` so far.

Also, this isn't necessary but if anyone knows how to add when the users account was created, to this embed it would be very helpful. Or even a resource or couple? Thanks for reading.

Comment: `setFooter` appears to take [two inputs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/RichEmbed?scrollTo=setFooter) (string and icon url) not three. Error suggests this is the problem. Try modifying and sending again.

Comment: Change `.setFooter('Akasuki', version, client.user.avatarURL);` to `.setFooter(\`Akasuki ${version}\`, client.user.avatarURL);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used Cursed's solution (in comments):

"Change `.setFooter('Akasuki', version, client.user.avatarURL);` to `` .setFooter(`Akasuki ${version}`, client.user.avatarURL); ``"

Works perfectly! Thank you so much!